# How to change swatch image

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

How to change the image of swatches for disabled options.

By default, Magento put a vertical red line if the option is not available for all options.

I want to change the image to my custom image.

Answer (score 0):

To change the image of swatches for disabled options in Magento, you'll need to override the default template and CSS styles. Here's a step-by-step guide to help you achieve this:

1.**Create a new theme:**

In your Magento installation directory, navigate to **app/design/frontend.**

Create a new folder with the name of your theme, for example, **yourtheme.**

Inside the **yourtheme** folder, create two more folders: **Magento_Theme** and **web.**

2.**Override the template:**

In the **Magento_Theme** folder, create another folder called **templates**.

Copy the template file you want to modify from the Magento core files to the **templates** folder.

For example, to modify the swatch template, you would copy **swatch-renderer.phtml.**

Open the copied template file **(swatch-renderer.phtml)** in a text editor.

3.**Replace the default image:**

Look for the line of code that generates the image for disabled options. It might look like **<img ...>.**

Replace the existing image code with your custom image code.

For example, if your custom image is located in the **web** folder and its filename is **custom-image.png,** the code might look like: **getViewFileUrl('images/custom-image.png') ?>" alt="Custom Image">**.

4.**Save the changes to the template file.**

5.**Override the CSS:**

In the **web** folder of your theme, create another folder called **css**.
Inside the **css** folder, create a file called **_extend.less**
Open **_extend.less** in a text editor.

6.**Customize the CSS:**

Write CSS rules to modify the appearance of the swatch images for disabled options.

For example, you can target the specific swatch element and change its background image using the **background-image** property.

```
.swatch-attribute-option[aria-disabled="true"] {
    background-image: url('../images/custom-image.png');
    /* Add any additional styles as needed */
}
```

7.**Save the changes to the _extend.less file.**

8.**Deploy the static conten**

Run the following command from your Magento root directory to deploy the static content:

```
 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme="YourVendor/yourtheme"
```

9.**Clear the Magento cache:**

```
  bin/magento cache:flush
```

10.**Configure your store to use the new theme:**

Log in to your Magento Admin Panel.

Go to **Content > Design > Configuration.**

Select the store view where you want to apply the theme.

In the **Applied Theme** column, select your custom theme
**(YourVendor/yourtheme).**

Save the configuration.

```
       HOPE THIS IS USEFUL TO YOU
```